# Should I name the for loop's i variable part?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When using for loop I tend to use,

```
for i in list
```

Is this a bad practice? Is it better to name the `i` variable?

Comment: It's better not to name a variable `list`.

Comment: For readability you can name it after the meaning of the elements in the list. For example you have a list of distances. Then maybe you can write ```for distance in distances```. Anyways, it's a bad practice to use ```list``` as a variable name, because you are overwriting the base functionality.

Comment: It depends what's in the list and the nomenclature of the domain. If you always use `i` that's probably not right, but there are contexts where that's the perfect name.

Comment: `i` is more often used to name the indexes of a list, as  `for i, val in enumerate(mylist):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always be descriptive as it improves readability.

For example:

`for element in array:`

Not only does it help others, but also yourself, when you review your code after a few weeks or months or even years!.

This is also a fantastic [guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) for naming conventions and style guides by the author of himself.

Answer (score 0):

Naming the variable `i` is just a programming convention prevalent in the community. 
It's perfectly viable to use it, however you won't do any harm by using more descriptive variable names.

For example, when iterating over a list of names, you may go for:

```
for name in names:
```

For a throwaway variable, some people use underscore:

```
for _ in values:
```

However, as has been mentioned by others, you better not name your variable named `list`,
as that happens to be the name of the built-in function. See [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) table for more info.

If you insist on having the variable named something like `list`, use `_list` instead.